# Openshift application trying to load deleted classes

Tags: java, spring, persistence, openshift

I have deleted few existing classes as part of changes to my application. Once the changes are committed, application is built & re-deployed but startup fails with a 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'. But the class being reported (used to be a mapped super class for JPA entities) is renamed and old name is not referenced from anywhere within the code. Same application works fine when I deploy in my local tomcat.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much for helping me on this.

Comment: Delete your tomcat work directory... Tomcat does that sometimes when you redeploy an application

Comment: @StormeHawke Thank you very much. Deleting the work folder fixed the issue.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try deleting your Tomcat work directory and then restarting? Every so often back when I was using Tomcat it would fail to update the work directory upon redeploy, so that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Is your application setup to do a hot deploy? Are you deploying a war file or just pushing up the application code an letting it get built?  Try stopping and re-starting your application using the rhc app stop $appname command

Comment: I already tried restarting the application but of no use. I am using git push to build and deploy the application.

Comment: We've got a BugZilla ticket put in for this issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048294